# Finding a root and reduce a function over a finite field

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $F= \Bbb Z_2[x]/ \langle f \rangle$ with $f=x^3+x+1 \in \Bbb Z_2[x]$. Now consider f as an element of $F[x]$ and

a) show that there exists $\alpha \in F$ with $f(a)=0$
b) find $g \in F[x]$ with $f=(x-\alpha)g$
c) show that also $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^4$ are roots of $f$ over $F$ and write $f$ as a product of irreducible elements of $F[x]$

So I tried finding the root of $f$ over $F$ and it seems like $x^2+x$ and $x^2$ are both roots but I'm stuck on part b and c, when I divide $f$ by $x-\alpha$ I always get a remainder.

Am I approaching this the right way or maybe I'm missing something. Also I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around the $F[x]$, what should be the modulus of it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't quite follow: as an element of $\;\Bbb F[x]\;$ , we have that $\;f=0\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio That's what I thought when I had a look at it, part of the reason why I have no idea what to do :S

Comment: @DonAntonio, I believe the purpose of the question is to show that $F$ is the splitting field of $f$.

Comment: What do you mean by the "modulus" of $F[x]$?

Comment: As for $g$, work out the degree of $g$; then work out its leading coefficient; then the next coefficient; continue until you get to its constant term, for which you will want to make use of $\alpha^3+\alpha+1=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson For example all elements in Z_2/<p> would have a modulus of p when doing multiplication and such so I thought F[x] would have one as well.

Comment: OK, calculations in $F$ are to be carried out modulo 2 and modulo $f$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: In latter parts of the problem we are to view
$f(x)=x^3+x+1$ as an element of $F[x]$, where $F$ is the described field of 8 elements.  The "original" $x$ is forgotten as soon as we get the field $F$ constructed, and $\alpha=x+\langle f(x) \rangle$ takes that role. This is mild abuse of notation, but standard.

Comment: "Standard", @JyrkiLahtonen ? I can't see how: if you told me that you look at the polynomial $\,f(t)=t^3+t+1\in\Bbb F[t]\;$ then I could understand (I can't see what for, though), but if you use the same symbols then $\;f(x)=0\in\Bbb F[x]=\left(\Bbb Z_2[x]/\langle f\rangle\right)$ ...

Comment: @JonathanY. , I think so....yet the doubt remains.

Comment: The abuse of notation is that $x$ in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/(f(x))$ is different from the $x$ in $F[x]$. The formal polynomial $f(x)=(1,1,0,1,0,\ldots)$ makes sense over any field, here first over $\Bbb{Z}_2$ and then over $F$. Consider the following similar situation we are more familiar with. Even if we construct the field of complex numbers as the quotient ring $\Bbb{C}=\Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$, we can continue to view $x^2+1$ as a polynomial in $\Bbb{C}[x]$ also. No problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to use two indeterminates, so let us say that $F = \mathbb{Z}_{2}[y]/\langle f(y) \rangle$.

a) One of the roots of $f(x)$ is $y$ (or more precisely $y + \langle f(y) \rangle$).

b) Yes, divide as you suggest by $x - y = x + y$ to get
$$
x^{3} + x + 1 = (x + y) (x^{2} + y x + (1 + y^{2})).
$$

c) This is a general fact, as over a commutative ring of characteristic two, the map $u \mapsto u^{2}$ will be a ring homomorphism. So if $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$ you have $0 = f(\alpha) = \alpha^{3} + \alpha + 1$, and thus
$$
0 = (\alpha^{3} + \alpha + 1)^{2} = \alpha^{6} + \alpha^{2} + 1
=(\alpha^{2})^{3} + \alpha^{2} + 1 = f(\alpha^{2}).
$$

Comment: Thank you! It made so much more sense when I used a different notation for the x inside F.